# Blazor WebApp: Original exception: AADSTS700025: Client is public so neither 'client_assertion' nor 'client_secret' should be presented

Tags: c#, json, azure

I'm trying to use Microsoft Entra ID for authentication along with Microsoft Graph API to access the page, using Authorization Code Flow with PKCE for the App Registration, and locking down certain pages for specific Security Groups in Entra ID. I used Visual Studio to create the Blazor project, and used "Connected Services" to add a Microsoft Identity Platform to creat an app registration on my tenant. This worked fine, and I was able to access my page by authenticating using my Entra ID account. However, I added some extra lines in Program.cs, in order to facilitate me being able to add authorization and checking the users group memberships using Microfoft Graph, and that's when everything went wrong. I can authenticate with Entra ID and see my page fine until I add the 3 lines after "AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))". Then it gives me that error.

This does not work:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { "User.Read.All", "Group.Read.All" }) /*new string[] { "User.Read.All", "Group.Read.All" }*/
.AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
.AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

This works:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
```

I also have a Secrets.json conneted service, which only has the following json content:

```
"AzureAD:ClientSecret": "xxx-My Secret-xxx" //Not my actual secret, obviously
```

And this is my global "appsettings.json":
[image]

There is also another "appsettings.json" under "wwwroot" like this:[image]

however the content in the "appsettings.json" under "wwwroot" is like this:
[image]

Again, when I dont include the 3 lines after

```
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd))
```

- it works fine. I can log on with my Entra ID account just fine and use the page. However adding those three lines above it no longer works. I need to be able to make it so that for certain pages in the web app, only members of specific Security groups withing Entra ID can access them.

Here is how the app registration is set up:
[image]

[image]

How can I solve this? I tried making the ClientSecret value in Secrets.json a blank string, but then it groans and complains that I need to provide a Secret. When I don't, it complains I should.

Extra: It says: 0 web, 6 spa, 0 public
[image]

Very confused. Help?

Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { "User.Read.All", "Group.Read.All" }) /*new string[] { "User.Read.All", "Group.Read.All" }*/
.AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
.AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

app.Run();
```

Comment: Are you using Blazor server app or blazor webassembly?

Comment: @AsleshaKantamsetti - I am not 100% sure. When I created the project in Visual Studio 2022 I created a Blazor Web App project, and I think I chose "Interactive render mode: Server", but at this point I don't know how to verify this after the fact. I will include a picture of my Program.cs in the main post at the bottom.

Comment: can you provide program.cs in code format

Comment: @AsleshaKantamsetti  I added Program.cs in code format at the bottom now. Thanks for assisting!

Comment: can you provide your error details here.

Comment: @AsleshaKantamsetti When I launch the web app, I am asked to login to my Entra ID account. This is good. When I log in, I get exception in the title, that the client is public and not expecting client secret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following code to implement Azure AD with Graph API in a Blazor web app using Interactive Render Mode: Server.

I connected Azure AD through Connected Services in Visual Studio.

**Program.cs**:

```cs
using BlazorApp26.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { "User.Read.All" }) 
.AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
.AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
                    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
      options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();
builder.Services.AddScoped<SignOutSessionStateManager>();
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
});
var app = builder.Build();
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);   
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().Add(
    context =>
    {
        if (context.HttpContext.Request.Path ==
                "/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/logout")
            context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/");
    }));
app.UseAntiforgery();
app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();
app.Run();
```

This is My root folder appsetting.

**appsettings.json**:

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "microsoft.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "<TenantId>",
    "ClientId": "<ClientId>",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "ClientSecret": "<ClientSecret>"
  },
  "MicrosoftGraph": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes":  "User.Read.All"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

**wwwroot/appsettings.json**:

```json
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "ClientId": "<ClientId>",
    "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/M365x56209219.onmicrosoft.com",
    "ValidateAuthority": true
  },
  "MicrosoftGraph": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "User.Read.All"
  }
}
```

> Blazor  WebApp:  **Raw**  exception:  AADSTS700025:  **"client_assertion"**  **and**  **"client_secret"**  **should**  **not**  **be**  **displayed**  **because**  **the**  **client**  is  public

For the above error, click on App registration, then Authentication -> Add a platform -> Web, and it will redirect to configure the web. I added my redirect URI as shown below.

[image]

[image]

Enable Access token and ID token as shown below.

[image]

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure why, but your response made it work for me.I see you have added some extra methods to Program.cs that I did not use. Thanks for you assistance.